# Bootstrap v4.0 hamburger items on the right

Tags: bootstrap-4

Silly question: Working with Bootstrap v4.0. How can we put 'hamburger' items on the right side, instead of left side? 
Basically, I want this, just opposite sides
[image]

Another example: I need items to be just under 'hamburger', not on the left side:
[image]

I looked on http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/, [Bootstrap 4 navbar items on right side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40178386/bootstrap-4-navbar-items-on-right-side), [Collapse button on right side of navbar in bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185631/collapse-button-on-right-side-of-navbar-in-bootstrap-4)

Everybody talks about items in regular navbar. But what about items in collapsed navbar?

*with Bootstrap 3 everything worked fine, I just cannot find how to do it with Bootstrap v4.0.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review our [SO Question Checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer. Please paste a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of the code you have already tried.

Comment: everything is explained in the BS documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#toggler

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check the code below.

I've added the classes `float-right`, `text-right`, and `pr-3` (padding-right) to the div **inside** `navbar-collapse` div.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
      <div class="navbar-nav float-right text-right pr-3">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: is it possible to have toggler on the right ant collapsed items also on the right when you click on toggler?

Comment: In this case you should move the `navbar-brand` `<a>` before the toggler button in your code.

Comment: nice..such simple solution. Thank You very much!